# Append after focused child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a div with the ID `wrapper`, and I am using `.append()` to insert some content at the end of that div, like this:

```
$("#wrapper").append('Some divs and input fields');
```

However, I also want the option to insert a new child after the focused `content` div in the wrapper.

So if the HTML output looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
             First div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the input field in the first `content` div is in focus, I want to insert an element after that div, so I get this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
             First div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Third div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What triggers the `append`?

Comment: The append function is triggered by pressing enter.

Comment: Not a jquery expert but I guess if you have the I'd of the inner divs then you can handle this in the focus handler of the input's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(':focus')` will give you the focused element and `closest('.content')` gives its ancestor with class `content` and then you use `after` to insert the element.

```
$(':focus').closest('.content').after(whatever_element_you_want_to_add);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? maybe add some reference too :)

Comment: Just did, hope it's better now :)

Answer (score 2):

As you said

> The append function is triggered by pressing enter.

You can try this code. It gets triggered on pressing `enter key` on `input` :

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
             First div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="subcontent">
            Second div
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('#wrapper').on("keyup",'input',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).closest('.content').after("<div class='content'> <div class='subcontent'>Some div<input type='text' /> </div></div>")
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/4d1c8ofe/1/)